# react-native-camera face detection

Tags: react-native, face-detection, react-native-camera

Using [react-native-camera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-camera) to attempt facial recognition is not working.

```
<RNCamera
faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
onFacesDetected={(face)=>{
   console.log(face)
 }}
/>
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: cannot read property fast of undefined" triggered by faceDetectionMode={RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.fast}
```

When I print out

```
console.log('RNCAMERA',RNCamera.Constants)

{"AutoFocus": {"off": 0, "on": 2},.....,  "FaceDetection": {}, .....}
```

Face detection is empty.

I'm using react-native-camera@3.42.2

I have also followed [these](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements) steps to get it working. Testing for ios only at the moment.

```
pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native- camera', subspecs: ['FaceDetectorMLKit']

cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

The error i get on pod install is

```
Unable to find a specification for `MLImage (= 1.0.0-beta1)` depended upon by `MLKitVision`
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I don’t know this library but it looks like the current version is 4.0.1.  It’s very possible that they were major changes between 3 and 4 and that you are trying to use new syntax on an old version.  Try upgrading to v4 and see if it works.

Comment: That release was about 8 days ago. Was using the correct version of documentation for 3.42.2 and resources.

Comment: @lindaPaiste you seem quite knowledgeable on RN. Ideally what i want to accomplish is 1. Live Face capture (ensure user is not a photo i.e. https://osamaqarem.com/blog/intro-to-liveness-detection-with-react-native is a good example it has some draw backs but will suffice.). 2. Process front and back of a National ID and read the MRZ.

Very surprised there isn't free libraries for these two functions. Seen some paid ones but their costs are not feasible. 

Any ideas of where to look.

Comment: Interesting requirements.  The fraud detection aspect of it is not something that I’ve ever dealt with personally.  Maybe there’s a TensorFlow.js model that meets your needs?  There’s one for [face landmark detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/face-landmarks-detection), but that doesn’t address live vs screen detection.

Answer (score -1):

```
//This code will detect and count face

import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, DeviceEventEmitter, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Camera, useCameraDevices } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import { showFloatingBubble, hideFloatingBubble, requestPermission, initialize } from "react-native-floating-bubble"
import FaceDetection, {
  FaceDetectorContourMode,
  FaceDetectorLandmarkMode,
} from 'react-native-face-detection';
const App = () => {
  //REf Variables
  const camera = useRef<Camera>(null);

  //Hooks
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string | undefined>();
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState<boolean>(false);

  //Camera Vars
  const devices = useCameraDevices('wide-angle-camera');
  const device = devices.front;
  const options1 = {
    landmarkMode: FaceDetectorLandmarkMode.ALL,
    contourMode: FaceDetectorContourMode.ALL,
    rotation: 0,
    cameraOrientation: 'landscapeRight',
  };

  const handleInterval = async () => {
    if (camera.current !== null) {
      try {
        const buffer = await camera.current.takePhoto({});
        const faces = await FaceDetection.processImage(buffer.path, options1);
        if (faces.length > 0) {
          alert(`Total No of faces are ${faces.length}`);
          // console.log("Total No of faces are ${faces.length}===============",`Total No of faces are ${faces.length}`)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in handleInterval:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(handleInterval, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {

    const getPermissions = async () => {
      try {
        const newCameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
        console.log('permission==============', newCameraPermission);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error in getPermissions:', error);
      }
    };
    requestPermission()
    .then(() => console.log("Permission Granted"))
    .catch(() => console.log("Permission is not granted"))
    
// Initialize bubble manage
initialize()
    .then(() => console.log("Initialized the bubble mange"))
  showFloatingBubble(10, 10)
    .then(() => {      
  
  });
  
  getPermissions();
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("floating-bubble-press", (e) => {
    setShowCamera(prevShowCamera => !prevShowCamera)
  //   Alert.alert(
  //     'Alert Title',
  //     'alertMessage',
  // )
  //  console.log("camera===============","I am pressed")
  });

  }, []);


  if (device == null) return <ActivityIndicator />;

  return (
    <>
      {showCamera && 
      <Camera
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        device={device}
        ref={camera}
        isActive={true}
        photo={true}
      />
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.